# Android Eclipse drawable error

Tags: android, eclipse, image, drawable

When I add image on my app and click **Project > Clean.**
I have this problem and I can't run my app. 
What i doing wrong? 
https://imgur.com/RHulhTf

Answer (score 0):

your image name needs to begin with a letter and not a number

your image name cannot contain upper case letters

your image name cannot contain anything other than letters and numbers